# Creating inner-accordions into an empty accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with inner-accordions : the destroy-recreate method to refresh an accordion after adding some panels doesn't work correctly.

When I click on the button in the second accordion it adds a section into it. But the sub-accordion doesn't work (in spite of the desctruction-recreation of the accordion).
You can see the code and test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/YL99D/2/

BUT if I modify the HTML code by adding an initial section in the #sections div, it works perfectly when I click the button (Code and demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/YL99D/3/ )

I have also looked at the generated HTML codes using Firebug and I have found something interesting.
First look at the code generated when I have put a hard-coded section in the #sections div :

```
<div id="sections" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
    <div id="sections_new1">
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Section</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="display: block;">
            Section content :
            <br>
            <div class="sub-accordions ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
                        <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sub accordion.</a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">Sub accordion content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now look at the code generated when I let the #sections div empty :

```
<div id="sections" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
    <div id="sections_new1">
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Section</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="display: block;">
            Section content :
            <br>
            <div class="sub-accordions ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
                <div class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-state-hover" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sub accordion.</a>
                    </h3>
                    <div>Sub accordion content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result is that classes are badly set.
Do someone have an idea of what is causing this problem ?

**[EDIT]** : Complete rephrasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT : I have found the source of the problem.**
Here are the code and demo : http://jsfiddle.net/YL99D/5/

If you have the same problem I've had, take care of creating accordions when they really exist and are not empty. Otherwise it seems it causes many problems.
Moreover, I have used objects to store accordions' options, instead of using the method data(). Thus, the accordions seem to react a normal way even after adding HTML elements after the DOM has been loaded.

---

I have partially found a solution. Instead of defining data related to the selectors, simply define objects which contain the options.

Here are the code and demo : http://jsfiddle.net/YL99D/4/

BUT it does not work when we add a sub-accordion into an existing (not javascript-generated) accordion.

So the problem is still no solved

Answer (score 0):

Accordion only updates the css on startup, not when you add something dynamically to it.  Your best bet may be to to do something like this when you want to add (or substract) something:

```
var activeEl = $('#questions').accordion('option','active');

$('#questions').append('<h3><a href="#">foo</a></h3>');
$('#questions').append('<div>bar</div>');

$('#questions').accordion('destroy').accordion({active:activeEl});
```

---

Added:
Here, btw, is an example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/NkVQJ/

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Your code up top is fragmented, so I'm working off of some base assumptions on how your code works.

Comment: I have tried to simplify my base example : http://jsfiddle.net/435bD/6/
I have also tried your solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/435bD/7/
But I does not work (unless I did something wrong)

Comment: Wow.  Um.... Your selectors are over the top, which was actually your problem.  Your core selector was horked.  Here's my fiddle, which is a fork of yours and highlights the deltas in all caps:  http://jsfiddle.net/2NqQJ/

Comment: Yes the selectors where probably buggy, my fault. I have not well transformed my code into an easier one.
But just a couple of remarks from your fiddle. You said "you can't use a wrapper div and Accordion simultaneously", but we can. That's why I use `header: "> div > h3"` option in the accordion data ;)
Moreover, in you fiddle you have uncommented the `<div id="sections_new1">`, but that's what I would like not to have, otherwise it looks very similar to what I proposed in my question.
I want to generate sections even when the `sections` div is empty :)

Comment: I have completely rephrased my question and I have added some information, if it can help you ;)